# Триггер. SQL,PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, триггер, postgresql

Не могу понять, как задать условия в триггере.
Есть две таблицы: Нагрузка и Расписание
[image: Таблица нагругка и расписание]

Хочу задать условия («Чтобы нельзя было указывать в таблица "Расписание" одновременно перебывание в разных аудитория на одном уроке (моего учителя в табл нагрузка»)

Задал только базовые условия.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_rasp() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$        
BEGIN
IF ( d_day_week is null)    
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Не может быть пустым';
END IF;  
IF (classroom is null)  
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Не может быть пустым';
END IF;
IF (lesson is null)  
THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Не может быть пустым';
END IF;
END;  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgSQL;
```

Comment: *Чтобы нельзя было указывать в таблица "Расписание" одновременно перебывание в разных аудитория на одном уроке* Задача решается созданием уникального индекса `(дата, урок)` - это предотвратит наличие двух записей для одного и того же урока в один и тот же день. Триггеры не нужны.

Comment: только если будете использовать дату, а не день недели - не забудьте отборосить время (привести к началу дня).

Comment: А, можно как-то через триггер ? Мне просто именно он нужен...